# Compiling is slow if headers are copied to Azure Fire Share

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-storage

I want to build my c++ based application in Azure VM.  The ultimate goal is to create a build farm in the cloud, using Azure DevOps to orchestrate the build pipeline.  However, I need to first figure out how to build my application in a VM.

Compiling my application requires accessing third party software headers and lib such as Boost and libusb.  I want to put these 3rd party software in the Azure File Share, but the compilation (in Windows and Linux) of my app becomes stuck.

The application should compile on Windows and on Linux, and in both cases (MSBuild and g++) the compilation gets stuck (no error message complaining about a missing header).  I know that it gets stuck at trying to access the Boost headers, because as soon as I replace the remote Boost library with a local version, the compilation would work normally.

I follow MS documentation to setup the file share for Windows and Linux.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux

Why is the compiling so slow when the include directories are in Azure File Share?

Comment: When you said "gets stuck", did you mean it's stuck there forever or just very slow and will finally succeed?

Comment: If you only meant it's slow, you may want to try the Azure Premium Files which is still in public preview: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/premium-files-pushes-azure-files-limits-by-100x/